# How to Run pigpiod on boot

Tags: gpio, python, boot

In order to use pigpio Module in Python (remote GPIO for Raspberry Pi ), `pigpiod` has to be loaded to memory on each RPi.

1. what is the right way to to it ? during Ubuntu's boot or a part of Python's script ?
2. since It needs `sudo pigpiod`- how is it done (both Ubuntu and Python )?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
sudo systemctl enable pigpiod
```

will enable it to auto-start on boot.

```
sudo systemctl start pigpiod
```

will start it immediately (just a posh way of doing

```
sudo pigpiod
```

:)

If you change your mind,

```
sudo systemctl disable pigpiod
```

will undo the start-up behaviour. Similarly,

```
sudo systemctl stop pigpiod
```

will have an immediate effect.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu:

ou can add the command in the `/etc/rc.local` script that is executed at the end of startup.

Write the command before `exit 0`. Anything written after `exit 0` will never be executed.

Raspbian:

to execute commands "at boot", if autologin is enabled (since what it really does it execute them when the pi user logs in), i'd suggest editing the `autostart` file wich is in the `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/` directory.
just add these two lines at the end of the file:

```
@export DISPLAY=:0
@epiphany /path/to/your/file.png &
```

P.S. you need to have root permissions to edit `autostart`

Python:

if you want to execute commands in a python script just do this:

```
from os import system
system("sudo pigpiod")
```

Comment: For Raspbian, just use the Raspberry Pi Configuration utility and enable Remote GPIO in the Interfaces tab (the [Remote GPIO chapter](http://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/remote_gpio.html) in the updated gpiozero docs cover this). If I recall correctly, pigpiod should be started by default anyway but is limited to localhost only without this option

Comment: @DaveJones Remote GPIO is set to "ON", but `pigpiod` still need to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Answered extensively in [gpio zero doc](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/remote_gpio.html)

or [link from RaspberryPi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=103752)