# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send' pigpiod

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspbian-jessie, python-3, pigpio

So I create an another program that can run stepper motor clockwise and counter clockwise with a ramp up and ramp down in there  and adding limiter switch on GPIO 16 and 26 to stop the `pi.wave_send_using_mode(wid2, pigpio.WAVE_MODE_ONE_SHOT_SYNC)` giving a chain wave, this is my code:

```
import time
import pigpio

START_DELAY=600
FINAL_DELAY=500
STEP=1

GPIO=20

pi = pigpio.pi()

pi.set_mode(GPIO, pigpio.OUTPUT)
pi.set_mode(21, pigpio.OUTPUT)
pi.set_mode(26,pigpio.INPUT)
pi.set_mode(16,pigpio.INPUT)
#pi.write(21,1)
pi.wave_clear()

statee = 0
try:
    while True:

        pi.write(21,statee)
        pi.wave_clear()

        wf=[]
        offset = pi.wave_get_micros()
        for delay in range(START_DELAY, FINAL_DELAY, -STEP):
           wf.append(pigpio.pulse(1<<GPIO, 0,       delay))
           wf.append(pigpio.pulse(0,       1<<GPIO, delay))

        for i in range(500):
            wf.append(pigpio.pulse(1<<GPIO, 0,       FINAL_DELAY))
            wf.append(pigpio.pulse(0,       1<<GPIO, FINAL_DELAY))
        wf.append(pigpio.pulse(0, 0, offset))

        for delay in range(FINAL_DELAY, START_DELAY, STEP):
           wf.append(pigpio.pulse(1<<GPIO, 0,       delay))
           wf.append(pigpio.pulse(0,       1<<GPIO, delay))

        pi.wave_add_generic(wf)

        wid2 = pi.wave_create()

        #pi.wave_send_once(wid2)
        pi.wave_send_using_mode(wid2, pigpio.WAVE_MODE_ONE_SHOT_SYNC)

        if pi.read(26) == 0:
            pi. wave_tx_stop()
            pi.stop()
        if pi.read(16) == 0:
            pi.wave_tx_stop()
            pi.stop()

        time.sleep(0.75)
        if statee == 0:
            statee = 1
        elif statee == 1:
            statee = 0
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("\nCtrl-C pressed.  Stopping PIGPIO and exiting...")
    pi.wave_tx_stop()
    pi.stop()
```

the problem happen when the mottor run arround 5 - 10 minutes, I give an error message like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/home/pi/Desktop/ramp.py", line 49, in <module>
    if pi.read(16) == 0:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 1401, in read
    return _u2i(_pigpio_command(self.sl, _PI_CMD_READ, gpio, 0))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 989, in _pigpio_command
    sl.s.send(struct.pack('IIII', cmd, p1, p2, 0))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

So, what the cause of error in my code? Is that cause by `pi.read(26)` and `pi.read(16)`? Is there any other ways to stop or terminate `pi.wave_send_using_mode(wid2, pigpio.WAVE_MODE_ONE_SHOT_SYNC)` at the middle of it process? thank you
small note: I set pigpiod daemon start on boot by folow ([How to Run pigpiod on boot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/70568/how-to-run-pigpiod-on-boot)   KimSJ answer), is the method of runimg pigpiod cause this error? thank you

Comment: I've had it running for about half an hour without a problem.  Which version of pigpio are you using?  Check with `pigs pigpv`.  I don't remember any fixes in this area but it's probably best to be running the latest version (V68).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be the `pi.stop()` causing the problem.  I'm not sure what you intend but that terminates the connection to the pigpio daemon.

I think you should comment out the calls to `pi.stop()` after `pi.read(26)` and `pi.read(16)`.

Comment: oooh, actualy I just want to stop or terminate `pi.wave_send_using_mode(wid2, pigpio.WAVE_MODE_ONE_SHOT_SYNC)` process when the the stroke beld driver linear stepper motor when it touch reference limiter switch on `pi.read(26)` and `pi.read(16)`. Is that posible by just using `pi.wave_tx_stop()`? Thank You

Comment: @Jansebastian Yes, just call `wave_tx_stop`, that will stop any waves (including a wave chain).  No pulses will be sent until you start a new wave or wave chain.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely cause I can see: you have a rogue space in line 49:

`pi. wave_tx_stop()`

should be

`pi.wave_tx_stop()`